# Conditions for the preimage of a finite index subgroup to again be finite index?

Tags: group-theory

Let $H \leq G$ be a subgroup of finite index in $G$. Let $K \overset{f}{\to} G$ be a surjective group homomorphism. $f$ extends to a surjection $K/f^{-1}(H) \twoheadrightarrow G/H$. What are conditions on $K, f$ or $G$ for this latter surjection on cosets to have finite fibers?

Comment: $G'$ is any group which is the domain of a surjective group homomorphism into $G$.

Comment: Then you should not use the notation $G'$, which usually is the derived subgroup of $G$.

Comment: I forgot about that; thanks for the reminder. I'll change it to $K$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Just for the record, I don't agree with you about that. I find $G'$ much too useful a notation for it to be reserved for the derived subgroup, which I prefer to denote by $[G,G]$.

Comment: Of course the answer to the question is always; in fact $|K:f^{-1}(H)| = |G:H|$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for your comment. Are you saying that the induced map on the cosets is injective as well? Could you go into some more detail about why this is true?

Comment: Let $N=f^{-1}(H)$ and denote the induced map by $\bar{f}$. Then, for $k_1,k_2 \in K$,  $\bar{f}(Nk_1)=\bar{f}(Nk_2) \Rightarrow Hf(k_1)=Hf(k_2) \rightarrow f(k_1)=hf(k_2) \Rightarrow k_1 \in Nk_2$, for some $h \in H$.